# JSP Dropdown from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsp, drop-down-menu, psql

I'm very very new to jsp and postgresql and I want to add a dropdown menu to my jsp file.

There is table with Names and Numbers and all I want is getting the names displayed in the drop down

This is what I got so far. An empty dropdown with the right numbers of rows (4 as I have only for rows in my table) is displayed but no names!

```
<sql:query
dataSource="${db}"
var="result">
select name from customer
</sql:query>

<select>
<c:forEach
var="result"
items="${result.rows}">
<option value=${param.name}>${param.name}
</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

PS: i tried to find an answer but all the answers were about mysql but we are using psql :/

Answer (score 0):

Your option list has the right number or options but they're empty because the variable `param` doesn't exist.

You have:

```
<c:forEach var="result"  items="${result.rows}">
<option value=${param.name}>${param.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

`var` is the variable to be created from `items`, so you don't want it named the same as the items list. This is where you should be creating the variable `param`.  It should be:

```
<c:forEach var="param"  items="${result.rows}">
<option value='<c:out value="${param.name}"/>'><c:out value="${param.name}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
```

You should probably also do it like `<option value='${param.name}'>` since the field `name` is probably text rather than numeric.

Comment: It's still empty with the right number of rows.
I don'T get it why the values are not shown. Tried to find a tutorial for psql+dropdown in a JSP but couldnt find one.

Comment: Have you tried `<c:out value="${param.name}"/>` inside the forEach?

Comment: Yes ... :/
There you can see the result. Below is a table using the same query, just for a table ....
[link](http://balrog.wu.ac.at:8180/h9902875/testdrop.jsp)
    <sql:query
    dataSource="${db}"
    var="result">
    select name from kunde
    </sql:query>

    <select>
    <c:forEach
    var="param"
    items="${result.rows}">
    <option value=${param.name}/>${param.name}
    <c:out value="{param.name}"/>
    </option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>'

Comment: @user3658612, I'm updating my answer. I think that's the issue actually. Since you just defined that variable you have to use `<c:out` to print it. It won't just evaluate by putting it directly in the HTML.

Comment: hi! So simple :D instead of "param" I have to use any termn thats not used! Param is used for sending data to another form/jsp and therefore must not be used within this forEach :D
Thank you for your help!